Priority visa application - not straightforward email
I applied for a UK skilled worker dependent visa for my child 7 days ago under priority service. I got the ‘not straightforward’ email on Day 1 itself. However, no information request or any follow up email since then. Can we do anything about it? Has anybody else faced it?

You can learn more about this situation in this previous question and answers.

It could just be that recent changes to visa rules provoked a flurry of applications beforehand resulting in a backlog, which is being ‘managed’ by issuing such a response. Using the Priority service will have got you further up the initial queue but not necessarily much further if a) there’s a backlog and b) lots of applicants are using the priority service. A queue is a queue.

This e-mail means it will likely take longer than the usual time to decide this case.
If they need more information you will be asked for it. But I guess that it will be a case of someone else in their system will have to handle it who might be at an other location or has a higher stack of cases to handle.
